# Magento2 : cross origin issue on sub store

Tags: magento-2.1.7, subdomain

I have created a sub store in magento2, but on subdomain I'm getting below error in console.

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://sub.domain.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.  

at contents (https://domain.com/pub/static/version1525152785/frontend/Package/theme/en_US/jquery.js:3123:9)
```

Cross origin error coming for all js files.

For this I tried to change pub/static/.htaccess file to add `Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` but after this I'm getitng error `Access-Control-Allow-Origin has multiple value '*, *`

How to fix this issue?